# Hidden value not working in Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

If I use combobox like this :

```
<select>
<option value="select">Select</option>
<option value="one" selected>one</option>
<option value="two" disabled>two</option>
<option value="three" hidden>three</option></select>
</select>
```

Hidden value working. Value three hidden.

But, I use Chosen like this :

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script> 

<select class="chosen-select">
<option value="select">Select</option>
<option value="one" selected>one</option>
<option value="two" disabled>two</option>
<option value="three" hidden>three</option>
</select>



<script type="text/javascript">   
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
</script>
```

Hidden value not working. Value three not hidden.

How do I get Chosen to hide an option with the hidden attribute set as in three?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the plugin perhaps?

Comment: You might set the first option to empty so "chosen" can use a placeholder instead: `<select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Something">
    <option value=""></option>`

Comment: I reworded the question to make it more obvious your issue.  This fiddle shows that option three is indeed not hidden when chosen is used. http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/4awt46bp/

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions. I've solved my problem. `<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $('.chosen-select option[hidden]').hide();
    $('.chosen-select').chosen(); 
</script>`

Comment: Post that workaround as an answer and accept it (noting that it IS a workaround of the issue perhaps?)

Comment: I've been trying to find the best solution and in my opinion it is the best solution.

Comment: One downside is that if you do something like `$('.chosen-select option').eq(2).prop("hidden",true);` you then have to rerun that `.hide()` as well and just to note the CSS `option[hidden] {visibility: hidden;}` does not appear to work/fix this either.

Answer (score 0):

The `chosen()` method doesn't support the hidden attribute by default. Instead, you should use custom jQuery or inline style to hide options value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.chosen-select option').each(function() {
      var attr = $(this).attr();
      if(attr=='hidden'){
        $(this).hide(); 
      }
    });
});
```